# As a novice, how do I program my Atmega328p?

Tags: atmega328, bootloader, electronics

I bought a board which the above MCU is the atmega328p. Since I haven't used atmel MCU before, now it's a bit confusing. Are the ATMEGA and STM32 programmers not universal? What programming methods can this chip support? Is there serial programming or SWD programming? Need help. Many thanks!

Comment: "Are the ATMEGA and STM32 programmers not universal?" No, one is via ISP and the other one is SWD / JTAG, they are different. Most of the times the ATMega chip *on maker boards* comes preprogrammed with a bootloader that allows it to be flashed via serial (Optiboot). Using the Arduino IDE with the board "Uno" selected will work then. Otherwise, you need to construct a ISP programmer if you do not have one. See https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/ArduinoISP.

Comment: *I bought a board* - which board? Link to it?

Answer (score 4):

> **Are the ATMEGA and STM32 programmers not universal?**

They are not the same. As far as I know their programming arrangements are completely distinct.

> **What programming methods can this chip support?**

- Traditional AVR In-Circuit-Serial-Programming ([ICSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-system_programming)) using a 2x3 header pin connector and one of a variety of programmers such as the STK500 which has low-cost clones like the [Pololu AVR programmer](https://www.pololu.com/product/1300) (less than $10). These programmers typically connect to a PC's USB port and can be used either with the software development tools from Atmel (now Microchip) or using the Arduino integrated development environment (IDE) which uses a program named avrdude to communicate with the ATMega328P (or other AVR family MCUs). ICSP is sometimes called In System Programming (ISP). It uses the MCU's [SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface) interface and you have to be careful what other circuitry is attached to those pins when you program the device.
- Serial-port programming by communicating with a pre-loaded "bootloader" program installed in the ATMega328P. This is the normal way to use the Arduino IDE but it depends on having that bootloader installed. Most bare ATMega328Ps are sold without this bootloader installed. All "Arduino" boards will have a bootloader installed in their MCU and many will have a serial-to-USB interface on-board so that the board can be plugged in to a PC directly. Otherwise you would need a USB-to-Serial interface like the [Adafruit FTDI friend](https://learn.adafruit.com/ftdi-friend) or many others.

There is also a [high-voltage programming](https://microchipsupport.force.com/s/article/How-to-perform-High-Voltage-Programming-on-AVR-devices) method but that isn't something a novice would need to use. I believe it is most often needed when you have configured the MCU in such a way that the above methods cannot be used. For example after having disabled the reset pin so it can be used as an IO pin that can be pulled to GND without resetting the MCU.

You can use an Arduino to emulate a programmer and use that to program boards that lack a USB serial interface. This is called [Arduino as ISP](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/ArduinoISP)

Microchip's newer generation of AVR MCUs use a different programming method than ICSP called [UPDI](http://www.technoblogy.com/show?2OJT).

Answer (score 1):

> What programming methods can this chip support? Is there serial programming or SWD programming?

The Arduino IDE (a free download) supports programming in C++. The IDE pre-processes your code (which they call a "sketch") slightly but it is still C++.

You can drop into assembler if you absolutely must, but the C++ compiler does a good job of producing efficient code, almost always.

With the assistance of a serial interface (many Arduinos, like the Uno, have one built-in connected to a USB interface) you can quickly and easily upload your code. The wherewithal to do that is built into the IDE.